# Do I have an access to data from ManyToManyField inside overridden save() method?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have overridden save() method and I tried to iterate my ManyToManyField(it's the "service") like:

```
for d in self.service.all():
self.price = 'Something'
```

But it doesn't work. Of course I did "super().save(*args, **kwargs)" before that.
Maybe I can't have an access to retrieve data from ManyToManyField inside Model?

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
    for i in Services_prices.objects.all():
        ccar = i.car
        sservice = i.service
        if ccar == self.car:
            for d in self.service.all():
                self.price = 'Anything'
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Have you overriden the save() method in your model or a model form? Could you post the code of your save() method?

Comment: In my model, of course. My save() method is too much big. I'll put the important part of it.

Comment: Why do you need those data there? can't you do it after the m2m have been saved too?

Comment: I need those data for some calculations and then an answer will be at the "price" field in the Model.

Comment: I think you should use `m2m_changed` signal.